# If Jesus was God, then why did he pray?

Tags: life-of-jesus, trinity, prayer

I don't know much about Christianity so I was watching this video:
[Is Jesus God?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPRcySFenL4)

I was stunned by the following things:

1. At the start of the debate Stanley Sjoberg says Jesus is the Son of God.
2. Near the 21:30 mark, the pastor mentions, "you see Jesus is not the son of God". At the beginning he said "Jesus is the son of God". After that he said "Jesus is the God" and then "Jesus is equal to God". Is he equivocating here or what is going on?
3. If Jesus was God, then why/to whom did he pray? How many Gods are there?
   How many gods are there in Christianity? If there is a god superior/bigger than Jesus, then why are there no Church/temple for those gods? Why do people not worship them?

Comment: According to whom? I do see that as as a proof Jesus _isn't_ God. According to the pastor?

Comment: If you need to clarify your question please do so by editing your question to be more clear, not commenting (much less picking a fight in comments). You asked what Christians believe, you'll get an answer. Whether you agree with it or not is another thing, and it is not the job of this site to convince you or "prove" a position.

Comment: @Shakeeb Shaheen. You do not understand what prayer meant for Jesus so your question is nonsensical. Prayer has nothing to do with whether Jesus is God.

Comment: You are confused because you do not understand what prayer is, it is nothing more than talking to God. Since our God is one in three persons why would you expect them not to converse with one another?

Answer (score 10):

There is **one** God who has revealed himself in **three** persons.

1. **The vast majority of Christians across all major sects agree that Jesus is both the Son of God and God.** This has been articulated many mays, but is not easy to explain in the confines of language. He is not the "son" as is a physical offspring as the result of sexual relations, but in another sense of being "begotten". Not created (as he always existed), and not lesser than (as they are one God) but having a defined relationship in himself. This is the classic issue knows as the "Trinity"—one God in three persons, all fully God not separate beings.

   We don't know (because we aren't told) *exactly* why God is this way, just that he is and this is how he has revealed himself to us. God himself chose to become a man, to reveal himself to us in human flesh, the God-man Jesus Christ—100% God, 100% man.

   One famous articulation of this can be found in the [Athanasian Creed](http://www.ccel.org/creeds/athanasian.creed.html):

   > Neither confounding the persons nor dividing the substance.
   >
   > For there is one person of the Father, another of the Son, and another of the Holy Spirit.
   >
   > But the Godhead of the Father, of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit is all one, the glory equal, the majesty coeternal.
   >
   > Such as the Father is, such is the Son, and such is the Holy Spirit.
   >
   > The Father uncreated, the Son uncreated, and the Holy Spirit uncreated.
   >
   > The Father incomprehensible, the Son incomprehensible, and the Holy Spirit incomprehensible.
   >
   > The Father eternal, the Son eternal, and the Holy Spirit eternal.
   >
   > And yet they are not three eternals but one eternal.
   >
   > As also there are not three uncreated nor three incomprehensible, but one uncreated and one incomprehensible.
   >
   > So likewise the Father is almighty, the Son almighty, and the Holy Spirit almighty.
   >
   > And yet they are not three almighties, but one almighty.
   >
   > So the Father is God, the Son is God, and the Holy Spirit is God;
   >
   > And yet they are not three Gods, but one God.
   >
   > So likewise the Father is Lord, the Son Lord, and the Holy Spirit Lord;
   >
   > And yet they are not three Lords but one Lord.
2. Having listened to Pastor Stanley's address, he seems quite clear. You may not *like* or *fully understand* what he is saying, but he isn't equivocating or being irrational. His representation of what the Bible says about Jesus is rather accurate and would be agreeable to most Christians of every major sect.

   The statement at 21:30 is quite plain but you have taken it out of context. He says "Jesus is not the son of God in the same way that I am the son of my Father". In this section he is defining his terms and making it what he does or does not mean. He goes on to explain how God's existence transcends the physical creation and we only exist in him. Therefor our physical relationship to our fathers is just a small aspect of a son/father relationship and what God means when he says that Jesus is his son is much more than that. All the way up to minute 28 he expands on the idea of God's "begetting" a son transcending our understanding of the physical world.

   On a few minor points unrelated to the person of Jesus he wanders a little bit from broadly accepted teachings. For example his theology seems to be dispensational and pre-millenial. His eschatology is not important for this question whether those views are correct or not, but you should be aware that there are differences between major Christian sects on those issues. Likewise the bit in minute 43 about no-cost would be disputed by a number of Christian perspectives.
3. As for why Jesus prayed, there are several explanations. One is simply that as a man he demonstrated how to live in a proper relationship with God. He was a perfect role model for men and therefore did what men should do. Additionally as one of the persons of the God-head he was in fellowship with his Father.

   Of course there are no other superior beings nor churches or temples dedicated to any other in true Christianity because we believe in only one God.

Comment: If  vast majority will say sun rises in west dose it mean sun rises in west..Answer is big nooooooooo.. Still i din got my ans other then beating around the bush or bulling in the eye."Whom jesus prayed?"How many gods are there in Christianity.If there are god superior/bigger there then Jesus, then why there no Church/temple for those gods .Why people dont worship them

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen If you haven't gotten your answer it is because you are not reading—either my words or the articulations of other Christianity. Pastor Stanley said it plainly, I said it in bold face at the top of my answer, and the creed I quoted articulates it in detail. The answer is in front of you. If you prefer to imitate Mr. Deedat's illogical and irreverent arguments rather that really investigating the issue you have nobody to blame but yourself.

Comment: @Caleb. Your answer is a little confusing. 'He was a perfect role model for men and therefore did what men should do.' Most Christians do not and adamantly refuse to do what Jesus did. He was therefore not a role model for them and as your answer is based on majorities, that cannot be why Christians pray. (The answer to the question is actually in the meaning of prayer as it was understood by Jesus not by modern Christians.)

Comment: @gideonmarx Just because all of us do a bad job of following the model doesn't invalidate Jesus prayer as a role model. Find me any major Christian group that believes Christ's prayers were _not_ exemplary of how we should pray. Most of them would agree with you that many/most professing Christians do a poor job at living up to the standard, but they rarely deny this doctrinal position.

Comment: Now that, that point has been made I am happy with the rest of the answer +1. (That is that most Christians believe that Jesus Christ was a role model that they should follow.)

Comment: @Caleb if man were able to live as Jesus showed us he would not have had to come down to Earth, it was because we cannot keep the law as Jesus did that his death on the cross and his resurrection are both elements required for our acceptability in Heaven, and only when we give our short comings to Jesus to be sacrificed on the cross, can they be forgiven since only Jesus could live a perfect and sinless life. Since Jesus was God as a part of the trinity it was not possible for him to disobey.

Comment: @gideonmarx please see my comment to Caleb.

Comment: @Bye I'm aware of all that but it's not really the point of this question or answer.

Comment: @Caleb I had no doubt that you were that was just to remind you and Gideonmarx that we puny humans are unable to live perfect lives no matter how hard we try, even though some do not put much effort into it.

Comment: There is one God who *has revealed himself in three persons* seems to be inaccurately stated.

Answer (score 5):

**How many Gods do we have?** One and only one!

**How many persons are there in God?** Three and only three!

**Who are them?** Father, Son and Holy Spirit.

> Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the
>   name of the Father and of the Son and of the Holy Spirit (Matthew
>   28:19, NIV)

**Do we worship them separately?** NO! Because they are ONE.

**What are their roles?**

1. The Father plays the role of a father; the Son and the Spirit does the will of the Father.

   > For I have come down from heaven not to do my will but to do the will
   >   of him who sent me. (John 6:38, NIV)
2. The Son plays the role of a mediator between God and mankind.

   > For there is one God and one mediator between God and mankind, the man
   >   Christ Jesus (1 Timothy 2:5, NIV)
3. Holy Spirit was sent by the Father to guide our hearts to God.

   > But the Advocate, the Holy Spirit, whom the Father will send in my
   >   name, will teach you all things and will remind you of everything I
   >   have said to you. (John 14:26, NIV)

**Why did Jesus pray?** Because He is a mediator between God and mankind.

**The identity of Jesus Christ:** Jesus has many titles such as -

1. The Word of God (John 1:1)
2. The Son of God (Luke 22:70, 1 John 4:15)
3. The Lamb of God (John 1:29)
4. The Son of man (Luke 9:22)
5. And much more. [See more titles here.](http://www.gotquestions.org/names-Jesus-Christ.html)

OK. I think that's enough for now. If you are still confused about the Trinity and the mysterious identities of Jesus, I can't help anymore but to redirect you to a video, ["Ravi Zacharias explains the Trinity"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c9gwoZNudCI).

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen If you like to chat around, please come here. Someone(not me) might reply to your comments, if they are interested or have the time to talk. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/the-upper-room

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen This is not a debate forum. You asked a question asking about Christianity's perspective. You don't have to agree with answers, but this isn't the place to argue about whether they are right or not.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other excellent answers given here, Jesus gives a reason for His prayers in John 11:

> John 11:41b-42  “Father, I thank You that You heard Me. I know that You always hear Me, but because of the crowd standing here I said this, so they may believe You sent Me.”

He said this as a prayer, after calling Lazarus out from the tomb. There was no recorded prayer beforehand asking God to raise Lazarus, but when Christ called it nonetheless happened, and for the benefit of His listeners He then established by whose power He had called Lazarus from the tomb.

I would additionally suggest that prayer helps us remember where our answers come from. God knows our needs, but if we did not ask Him to supply them we might not recognize His provision when it comes, and so err. Prayer, like praise, is a necessary part of giving all glory to God.

Answer (score -1):

"
THE HOLY TRINITY

Our LORD JESUS CHRIST, the ONE AND ONLY TRUE GOD is called by three names, viz., GOD the FATHER; GOD the SON; and GOD the Holy Spirit. GOD the FATHER came into this world as Saviour with the name JESUS CHRIST to save sinners of the world.

“...Thou art the CHRIST, the SON of the living GOD.”
St. Matthew 16:16

Thus, GOD the FATHER came into this world as the SON. HE HIMSELF is the GOD the SON. HE suffered terribly for sinners and died on the cross and was buried. JESUS CHRIST resurrected HIMSELF on the third day and appeared alive to many for forty days. On the 40th day after HIS resurrection, JESUS CHRIST went up to heaven before the eyes of HIS disciples.

After our LORD JESUS CHRIST had gone up to heaven, HE sent the Holy Spirit, the holy power or the holy strength to live a holy life, into the world on the day of Pentecost, the 50th day of HIS resurrection, as HE had promised HIS disciples. Thus, JESUS CHRIST HIMSELF came into this world as the Holy Spirit. HE HIMSELF is the GOD, the Holy Spirit. Thus the FATHER, the SON, and the Holy Spirit are together and ONE. So the LORD JESUS CHRIST is called the 'GOD of the Holy Trinity'. Therefore, it is a great truth that the GOD who is called by the names the FATHER, the SON and the Holy Spirit is ONE GOD only.

It is said in the Holy Bible,

“For unto us a child is born, unto us a son is given: and the government shall be upon HIS shoulder: and HIS name shall be called Wonderful, Counsellor, The Mighty GOD, The everlasting FATHER, The Prince of Peace.” 
Isaiah 9:6

From the above verse, anyone can understand that the mighty and  wonderful GOD, the SON is the everlasting FATHER; and the GOD, the everlasting FATHER is the SON, the LORD JESUS CHRIST, who came into this world as a child to save and redeem sinners from their sins.

When our LORD JESUS CHRIST was in the world, HE said with HIS most holy mouth,

“...He that hath seen ME hath seen the FATHER; ...”
St. John 14:9

“I and MY FATHER are one.” 
St. John 10:30

It is also said in the Holy Bible,

“But to us there is but one GOD, the FATHER, of whom are all things, and we in HIM; and one LORD JESUS CHRIST, by whom are all things, and we by HIM.”
 I Corinthians 8:6
“Now the LORD is that (the) Spirit: and where the Spirit of the LORD is, there is liberty.” 
II Corinthians 3:17

Moreover GOD, the FATHER, the ONLY TRUE GOD is the Holy Spirit. HE is without form and is invisible. GOD, the SON or the LORD JESUS CHRIST took the human form; GOD, the SON or the LORD JESUS CHRIST was visible. GOD, the Holy Spirit has no form and is invisible. The ONLY TRUE GOD, the FATHER who is the Holy Spirit HIMSELF is GOD, the SON who is with form; and GOD, the Holy Spirit who is without form. GOD the FATHER, the ONLY TRUE GOD works as Saviour to save sinners from their sins, with the name GOD, the SON and Saviour; and with the name the Holy Spirit, HE works to strengthen people to live a holy life. The two immensely glorious works of GOD, the FATHER are the work of salvation and the work of strengthening to live a holy life. These two functions are performed by the ONLY TRUE GOD, GOD the FATHER HIMSELF. Therefore, there is no reason to have any doubt over the fact that GOD is the ONE and the ONLY ONE who involves HIMSELF in various activities.

We know that the one and only sun gives warmth and light. Like the one and the same sun that gives warmth and light, the ONE AND ONLY GOD, the FATHER performs the work of salvation and the work of strengthening people to live a holy life. The work of salvation is being done in the most holy name of JESUS CHRIST and the work of strengthening is being done in the most holy name of the Holy Spirit. The ONE GOD and the ONLY GOD and the ONE AND ONLY TRUE GOD, GOD the FATHER HIMSELF is doing these two activities.

Therefore, there is no reason for anyone to have a doubt over the fact that GOD is ONLY ONE and salvation and strengthening people to live a holy life are HIS two glorious works. Salvation means saving of people's souls from sins and their consequences. 
The Christian GOD is the Holy Trinity GOD-the unity of GOD the FATHER, GOD the SON and GOD the Holy Spirit as ONE GOD. The Christian GOD is the Holy Triune GOD-three functional Persons, GOD the FATHER, GOD the SON and GOD the Holy Spirit in one GODHEAD (I John 5:7). Mathematically saying, one into one into one = one (1 x 1 x 1 = 1). There is no change in the ONE GOD and the ONE AND ONLY TRUE GOD, the LORD JESUS CHRIST. In LORD JESUS CHRIST resides GOD the FATHER and GOD the holy Spirit.
The facts given above are divine secrets. None but the true servants of GOD can understand them. Anyone who reads the Holy Bible literally cannot understand the divine secrets. Though the holy scripture of the LORD has been written literally, it contains spiritual meanings and divine meanings. Only the true spiritual men can understand its exact meaning. Praise The LORD! Alleluia!    "

- taken from the Book titled "ONE GOD ONE PEOPLE" written by Sadhu. C. Selvaraj, Administrator and Trustee, Beginning Pentecostal Truth Church, Malavilai, South India 629161.